# EEPROM protocol misconception

Tags: c++, memory, stm32, i2c, eeprom

I am currently using a michrochip's eeprom ( 24cw160 ) connected with an stm32f4 (11RET) via i2c. The configurations and the connection seem to work as my logical analyzer prints some i2c messages (with ACK) and I can send data and receive data back. After reading the [reference manual](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/24CW16X-24CW32X-24CW64X-24CW128X-Data-Sheet-20005772B.pdf)(especially pages 13 and 18 that have the schematics for the two operations I am doing) I am expecting the code below to send the data 0,1,2... to the addresses after x10 sequentially and then receiving the same data back and printing them :

```cpp
while(true){

    HAL_Delay(1000);
    std::array<uint8_t,100> arr{};
    int counter=0;
    for(auto&i :arr){
      i=counter;
      counter++;
    }
    auto ret1 = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA(&hi2c1 , 0xa0 , 0x10 , 1 ,arr.data() , arr.size());
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    std::array<uint8_t,100> arr2{};
    arr2.fill(1);
    auto ret2 = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read( &hi2c1 , 0xa1 , 0x10 , 1 , arr2.data() , arr2.size(),100);
    printf("arr2:\n");
    for(auto i:arr2){
      printf("%d,",(int)i);
    }
    printf("\nWrite ret status: %d\nRead ret status: %d\n",ret1,ret2);
  }
```

Instead what I get on my terminal is :

```
arr2:
70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
Write ret status: 0
Read ret status: 0
arr2:
68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
Write ret status: 0
Read ret status: 0
```

Notice ,that the first line of prints has some differences with the second and the second is recurring (so the while true at the first time print a little bit different things than the others)  I honestly think I have confused myself with the constant parameters I give to `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write` and `read` and I would like some explanation on that too.
For more info comment me and I will provide all the necessary diagnostics/initializations etc.

Comment: Have you tried the non-DMA write version? You're not getting the result of the actual write, just the write setup.

Comment: `HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_DMA()` is non-blocking. To wait just 1 second after starting the DMA transfer isn't enough. Instead, wait until `HAL_I2C_MemTxCpltCallback()` has been invoked.

Comment: Also, is `MemAddSize` measured in bits? You're passing 16 to it with a device that has 11-bit words. I don't think that would be the issue, if it's even wrong at all, since it sends two bytes anyways, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Also also, do these writes happen as a single write? If so, then you're limited to writing to a single page, you can't cross 32-byte boundaries.

Comment: As far as I understand the examples, the HAL calls themselves convert 7-bit device address to the 8-bit read/write command. Try use 0x50 in both calls (rather than 0xa0 and 0xa1).

Comment: @ThomasJager I tried the non dma and it seems that 100ms timeout where enough for the return to be HAL_OK I will try the rest soon, thenk you all fo rthe suggestions

Comment: @user58697 I think it is quite the opossite as the header of all the I2C functions comments state: `* DevAddress Target device address: The device 7 bits address value
  *         in datasheet must be shifted to the left before calling the interface`

Comment: @ThomasJager I tried the comment about MemAddSize , more at my answer.Thank you so much!

Comment: regarding: `std::array<uint8_t,100> arr{};`  this is a C++ statement.  Not a C statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I managed to send a byte at whatever address I want . One noticed error on the previous code is the `MemAddress` parameter( third parameter of `HAL_I2C_Write_Mem`) ,because my eeprom is 11 bit addressable I should declare to hal that it is 16 and not 8 as the 5 extra bits are ignored bits ,but less than 11 might malfunction.

A second problem was that I was trying to write more than 32 bytes and I was reading only the first 32 as the protocol doesn't accept writing or reading more than one 32 byte page at a time. So here is the modified code with some comments on the changes:

```cpp
std::array<uint8_t,32> arr{0}; //32 bytes instead of something silly
unsigned counter=0;
for(auto&i :arr){
    i=counter;
    counter++;
}
// 0x20 is a start of a page so it can write all 32 bits
// I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT is the value 2 instead of 1 I had
// The extra 5 bits are ignored
// For the testing I call the blocking write
auto ret1 = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1 , 0xa0 , 0x20 , I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT , arr.data() , arr.size(),4);
HAL_Delay(4);
std::array<uint8_t,32> arr2{0};
arr2.fill(1);
auto ret2 = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read( &hi2c1 , 0xa1 , 0x20 , I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT , arr2.data() ,arr2.size(),4);
HAL_Delay(4);
printf("arr2: ");
for(auto i:arr2)
   printf(" %d,",(int)i);
printf("\nWrite ret status: %d\nRead ret status: %d\n",ret1,ret2);
```

Comment: the `std::` is a C++ statement not part of C

Comment: @user3629249 I know but it doesn't matter that much as hardware related questions are mostly connected to c and not c++ . If I could add more than 5 tags I would add c++ but thats the least important thing of my question as whatever std::array does here can de done with a traditional array (e.g. instead of `fill` you can iterate over the array) .